# How to set default cross fade animation for Glide V4

Tags: android, android-glide

With glide v4 default cross fade animation removed. I updated my Glide version to 4 and I want to set a default cross fade animation, not to set for every image load request.

I tried to do it in AppGlideModule extended class which name is "Generated API" at `setDefaultTransitionOptions` but I failed.

How can I set default cross fade animation in Glide v4?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did it with this code:

```
builder.setDefaultTransitionOptions(Drawable.class, DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade());
```

Comment: What is the default value of DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade()?

Comment: If you asking the default transition here it is: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transitions.html#default-transition

Answer (score 18):

Current way to do this in Glide:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
    .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Thank you but I have to change all image request if I use this way.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this way, it is simple you can also add duration to your transition

```
 Uri image= Uri.parse(url_of_the_image);
 Glide.with(context)
      .load(image)
      .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(duration_in_ms)) 
      .into(imageView);`
```

Comment: In this way I have to change my all image load requests.

Comment: I need to know what the image object is

Comment: I had added a new line in the answer for the definition of the image. Hope it will help you